# Deploying gnotty as part of a django project and getting: gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

Tags: django, gevent

Attempting to deploy a django project with gnotty as part of it, which works perfectly well on the localhost but as soon as I deployed and changed the GNOTTY_HOST to my domain, the GNOTTY_PORT to 80, and the GNOTTY_DAEMON to True, as well as the pid file with an absolute path to a pid file.
Now, when I try to use the app by going to mydomain.net/irc/ then connecting with a nickname, it loads and then I get "Took too long to connect, please try again" so I tried to run manage.py gnottify to see if I got an error and there it was: gnotty/0.2.5 [Bot: BaseBot] listening on http://mydomain.net/:80
gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname: ('http://mydomain.net/', 80)
Exception KeyError: KeyError(29425008,) in  ignored

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like dns isn't resolving.  Have you tried using dig our nslookup?